# Parse values from HTML element using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script

I am trying to parse HTML element by class on Google Sites,  my code is:

```
function doGet(){

  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch ('http://indicadoresdeldia.cl/').getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var menu = getElementsByClassName(html, 'span3 utm')[0];
  var output = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(menu);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);

}
```

Ween i run the code appear the nexte error message ReferenceError: "getElementsByClassName" is not defined.

i am trying to deploy the example for the next page: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html

Any ideas?

THanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looking at the site you ref to, "getElementsByClassName" is a function you should include in your project, see https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html#TOC-getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

According to that site, you should directly copy those functions to your project (source code available there) and then call them. That would alleviate each and every one of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html

```
function getElementsByClassName(element, classToFind) {  
  var data = [];
  var descendants = element.getDescendants();
  descendants.push(element);  
  for(i in descendants) {
    var elt = descendants[i].asElement();
    if(elt != null) {
      var classes = elt.getAttribute('class');
      if(classes != null) {
        classes = classes.getValue();
        if(classes == classToFind) data.push(elt);
        else {
          classes = classes.split(' ');
          for(j in classes) {
            if(classes[j] == classToFind) {
              data.push(elt);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```