# ReferenceError: "getElementsByClassName" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, getelementsbyclassname, urlfetch

Hi I keep getting an error when I try to run this code, saying:

> "getElementsByClassName" is not defined.

```
function doGet() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model').getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var menu = getElementsByClassName(html, 'vertical-navbox nowraplinks')[0];
  var output = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(menu);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse values from HTML element using Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218845/parse-values-from-html-element-using-google-app-script)

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html#TOC-getElementsByClassName

Comment: isn't it doc.getElementsByClassName() ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var menu = getElementsByClassName(html, 'vertical-navbox nowraplinks')[0];
```

With

```
var menu = doc.getElementsByClassName('vertical-navbox nowraplinks')[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'm very new to coding in general so still finding my bearings, I appreciate the help. I'm now getting this error message: 
"TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [Document: [DocType: <!DOCTYPE html>], Root is [Element: <html/>]]. (line 22, file "Code")"

Comment: Hey @user12546548, You are trying to call `getElementsByClassName()` on an [element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element.html) object. However, that method does not exist. Navigating nodes parsed using XmlService is not the same as navigating them using the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). I suggest you revise the methods in the [element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element.html) class to better understand how to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @user12546548 probably you get this error because you are working with an object, so you should try to work with the dom's elements. In this case, using document.getElementsByClassName('vertical-navbox nowraplinks')[0];

Answer (score 1):

Add `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` function definitions from https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html to the script